# Is it best practice to use a protected object in a parent class, or have it private with a protected/public getter?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

using a small example which has a hierarchy of:

- BaseModel
- OrderModel extends BaseModel

Inside the BaseModel i want to have an object `Faker` in any class which extends it, what is the **correct** approach here?

```
private Faker faker = new Faker();

protected Faker getFaker() {
    return this.faker;
}
```

---

```
protected Faker faker = new Faker();
```

---

I have opted for this:

```
public class Order extends BaseModel {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Order.class);

    private String orderName;
    private String orderAddress;
    private String orderEmail;
    private String orderPaymentType;

    public Order(String order_paymentType) {
        this.orderName = getFaker().name().fullName();
        this.orderAddress = getFaker().address().streetAddress();
        this.orderEmail = getFaker().internet().emailAddress();
        this.orderPaymentType = order_paymentType;
        LOG.info("Instantiating order: " + this.toString());
    }

    public String getOrderName() {
        return this.orderName;
    }

    public String getOrderAddress() {
        return this.orderAddress;
    }

    public String getOrderEmail() {
        return this.orderEmail;
    }

    public String getOrderPaymentType() {
        return this.orderPaymentType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [orderName=" + orderName + ", orderAddress="
                + orderAddress + ", orderEmail=" + orderEmail
                + ", orderPaymentType=" + orderPaymentType + "]";
    }

}
```

I opted for this and to be honest, I don't entirely know why, what is the correct way to handle this situation and more importantly **why?**

**Faker** is an object used to generate fake information basically.

Comment: Please take a few minutes and edit your question to tell us a bit about the overall design.  What is the use of this `Faker` object?  By the way, chances are this is duplicate of something.

Comment: `getter` is always better

Comment: Kotlin all the way xD. Seriously though, getter/setters are always the best way. They standardize the classes so that you know that any `getting` and `getting` will be though them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation in you design is that `Faker` will always be present in all models and that is a hard dependancy you should avoid. By now, the current Java best practice is to favour composition over inheritance.

So we can have an interface called DataProvider

```
interface DataProvider {
  String address();
   ....
}
```

And Fake would implement this address

`class FakeDataProvider implements DataProvider...`\
and now you can inject a DataProvider

```
public Order(String order_paymentType, DataProvider dataProvider){
  this.orderName = dataProvider.name().fullName();
  ....
}
```

And now you replace `Faker` with something else without touching Order code. So my answer is: don't use inheritance all together.

Comment: I assume my Order would then take a FakeDataProvider rather than the DataProvider as it has implemented the interface methods? I have scrapped the BaseModel altogether and created a DataProviderInjector which implements the DataProvider interface, then passed that in to the Order class constructor, also created a second constructor incase the user wants to manually pass in all order information without generating a fake one

Comment: @Jackofspace yes that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "getFaker().name().fullName()" in your sub-class, I think you'd better define some methods in your class BaseModel which provides functions to get fullname, streetAddress...Other than using Faker directly in your sub-class(Order)